# Animated UIImage in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

### Summary

When changing animated UIImage in a custom UITableViewCell. The animated image are not displayed properly when reloaded(often after scrolling around).

### Background

I try to implement a audio play list using table view. I need a icon in the custom cell indicating whether the cell's audio is playing.

1) Here's the view hierarchy:

```
------------------------------------
| custom UITableViewCell           |
|      ------------------------    |
|      |   UIImageView        |    |
|      |   ---------------    |    |
|      |   |  UIImage    |    |    |
|      |   ---------------    |    |
|      ------------------------    |
------------------------------------
```

2) And I have 2 images:

```
self.playIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play"];
self.playingIcon = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"sentencePlayingNow" duration:0.5f];
```

3) When one audio is playing, I set a isPlaying attribute in the custom UITableViewCell.

```
// self.icon is a UIImageView
- (void)setPlaying:(BOOL)isPlaying
{
    if (isPlaying) {
        [self.icon setImage:self.playingIcon];
    } else {
        [self.icon setImage:self.playIcon];
    }
    _isPlaying = isPlaying;
}
```

4) I reload the tableView like this

```
// oldPlayingIndexPath and newPlayingIndexPath indicates current playing row.
if (oldPlayingIndexPath || newPlayingIndexPath) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (oldPlayingIndexPath) {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[oldPlayingIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
        if (newPlayingIndexPath) {
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newPlayingIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
    });
}
```

### My Question

When I set isPlaying attribute. If self.playingIcon is a static UIImage, all is well. If self.playingIcon is animated like I described above, It's either self.icon is not displayed or it displays self.playIcon(the static one)? Why is that?

The original screenshot:
[image: original]

After scrolling out and in:
[image: problematic]

### Update

Reply to @RoryMcKinnel: My cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SentenceTableViewCell";
    SentenceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


- (void)configureCell:(SentenceTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Sentence *sentence = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setTitle:sentence.text];

    if ([self.article.allowsEditing boolValue] || (sentence.audio_url.length > 0)) {
        [cell setCanPlay:YES];
    } else {
        [cell setCanPlay:NO];
    }

    cell.playIcon = self.playIcon;
    cell.playingIcon = self.playingIcon;
    cell.OKIcon = self.OKIcon;
    cell.isPlaying = self.currentPlayingIndexPath && [self.currentPlayingIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame;

    __weak EditViewController *weakSelf = self;
    cell.play = ^void() {
        [weakSelf playSentenceAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    };
    cell.stop = ^void() {
        [weakSelf.player pause];
        weakSelf.currentPlayingIndexPath = nil;
    };
    cell.edit = ^void() {
        weakSelf.tableView.editing = YES;
    };
}
```

Comment: is `playIcon` a property of your custom tableViewCell?

Comment: If self.icon is a UIImageView, do you not need to call `[self.icon startAnimating]`?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes. It's initialised in the view controller and passed to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I use [UIImage animatedImageNamed:] rather than UIImageView.animationImages

Comment: I believe that is really a utility that just loads multiple images with the same base name. I think you still need to call start?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel My problem is not the animatedImage is static but it is replaced by empty or other static image after scrolling around. Just to be sure, tried your suggestion...No luck. I also took a glance at the reference, no details about how the 2 methods are implemented. But it did animates when I just do [UIImage animatedImageNamed:] without starting animation.

Comment: Most likely due to your cellForRowAtIndexPath method being wrong. Can you show that code? You will need to set the cells Playing properties every time a cell is requested by index path to the right value.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel already updated in the original question, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I use self.currentPlayingIndexPath to control which cell's audio is playing. And cell.play cell.stop cell.edit all refresh the cell by reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: In the cell configuration, you do not seem to set the image for the cell again, unless I am missing something. i.e. You are not setting `cell.playing`, which seems to be where you set the image? You do set `cell.isPlaying` which you may have calling setPlaying in the setter, but don't have the code for that?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I set image for the cell in the setter of cell.isPlaying where getter=setPlaying, simply changed the getter's name.

Comment: @jchnxu I hope you mean you changed `setter=setPlaying` and not `getter=setPlaying`?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I changed setter=setPlaying on the property isPlaying.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the reusability. You need to make sure that when the cell is being reused or recreated the correct image is reloaded. One tip, You probably do not want the wrong icon to flash briefly before the correct one appears so I would set the imageView to nil in `didEndDisplayingCell` and always recreate the icon in `viewForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Once I suspect that it's due to reusability. But static UIImage do not have this problem. I tried setting it nil. Everything stays the same. However I did notice there's a flash, but rather a flash of the correct image then going back to the wrong one.